# How to subtract a query result from another query result in MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, stored-procedures

**1st query**

```
   (SELECT a.cat_id, 
          a.cat_name, 
          a.cat_description, 
          b.subcat_name, 
          b.subcat_description 
     FROM trade_categories a 
LEFT JOIN trade_subcategories b ON a.cat_id = b.cat_id 
    WHERE a.cat_name LIKE '%catty%' 
       OR a.cat_description LIKE '%catty%') 
UNION 
  (SELECT c.cat_id, 
          d.cat_name, 
          d.cat_description, 
          c.subcat_name, 
          c.subcat_description 
     FROM trade_subcategories c 
LEFT JOIN trade_categories d ON c.cat_id = d.cat_id 
    WHERE c.subcat_name LIKE '%catty%' 
       OR c.subcat_description LIKE '%catty%')
```

**2nd query :**

```
SELECT x.cat_id, 
       x.cat_name, 
       x.cat_description, 
       y.subcat_name, 
       y.subcat_description 
 FROM  trade_categories x 
  JOIN trade_subcategories y ON x.cat_id = y.cat_id 
 WHERE (   x.cat_name LIKE '%catty%' 
        OR x.cat_description LIKE '%catty%' ) 
   AND (   y.subcat_name NOT LIKE '%catty%' 
        OR y.subcat_description NOT LIKE '%catty%' )
```

I want to subtract the 2nd query result from 1st query result.

Comment: How about Query1 MINUS Query2

Comment: I tried it but shows sytax error

Comment: MINUS is not implemented in MySQL yet.

Comment: sorry... i couldn't visit the blog last day.. i was very busy with a work. :(

Answer (score 13):

http://www.bitbybit.dk/carsten/blog/?p=71

or 
example:

```
SELECT Name FROM employee1  WHERE name NOT IN (SELECT name FROM employee2);
```

Comment: I get a 403 forbidden when clicking that link....

You don't have permission to access /carsten/blog/index.php on this server.
Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can either do a NOT IN or a LEFT JOIN. I'd prefer a LEFT JOIN.

So for example,

```
SELECT `QUERY_ONE`.*
FROM `QUERY_ONE`
LEFT JOIN `QUERY_TWO` USING (`cat_id`)
WHERE QUERY_TWO.cat_id IS NULL;
```

where QUERY_ONE and QUERY_TWO are aliases for your two queries

Comment: without storing the data in separate tables... it there any other soltion for this...  shall v apply some conditions or something to link these 2 queries?

Answer (score 0):

```
   SELECT a.cat_id, 
          a.cat_name, 
          a.cat_description, 
          b.subcat_name, 
          b.subcat_description 
     FROM trade_categories a 
LEFT JOIN trade_subcategories b ON a.cat_id = b.cat_id
    WHERE a.cat_name NOT LIKE '%catty%' 
      AND a.cat_description NOT LIKE '%catty%'
      AND (b.cat_id IS NULL
        OR b.subcat_name NOT LIKE '%catty%' AND b.subcat_description NOT LIKE '%catty%')
```

Or, if the results of the two queries have been stored in (temporary) tables, you could use [@Abhay](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6380312/how-to-subtract-a-query-result-from-another-query-result-in-mysql/6381364#6381364)'s solution on them.